# Fire an event after Richtextbox Textchanged event

Tags: c#, wpf, events, richtextbox

I am writing a lexer and i also want my text editor to change the color of the keywords. While typing! like VS and ... ! but the problem is TextChanged event of a RichTextBox fires BEFOR adding the text to it.

Is there any pre defined event that fire write AFTER adding the text to the richTextBox ? if not how can i create one that fire write after entering the text!

PS : i am writing a WPF project!

```
private void rtxMain_TextChanged (object sender, TextChangedEventsArgs e) {
   visual.getLastWord();
}
```

Comment: `TextChanged` event fires after changing the text of `RichTextBox`. How do you get the text of it?

Answer (score 3):

`TextChnaged` event fires after changing the text of `RichTextBox`. Here is a working example of it:

```
private void richtextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string text = new TextRange(richtextBox1.Document.ContentStart, richtextBox1.Document.ContentEnd).Text;
    MessageBox.Show(text);
}
```

Whatever I type into the `richtextBox1`, it shows me the exact same value in the `MessageBox`. It means it fires the event after changing the `Text`.

Comment: so why the character that i enter doesn't show up in the textbox when i break point the textchanged event! when i place a breakPoint there the character that i entered add to the richtextbox right after the getLastWord() execution ! that's why i am saing this

Comment: @MohammadNej What ever you are saying you are not saying it very clear.  TextChanged fires after the text is changed.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the keyUp event it will fire when a key on the keyboard is let go off.

```
RichTextBox r = new RichTextBox();
r.KeyUp += (s, e) =>
{
    //your logic
};
```

You might need to add extra logic to avoid keypresses like shift which isnt hard to do and maybe not even neccesary.

Comment: i doesn't work to ! as i traced the my app the keyUp event happens before textChanged so it's useless :| !

Comment: You are doing something else wrong the keyup event fires after the letter is written in the richtextbox since letters are written on keypress and key up cant happen after it